# How to make border color red of a input filed using codeigniter formvalidation?

Tags: codeigniter

Php Codeigniter formvalidation and showing error with red color border instead of error message.What to do?

Comment: put your code here.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a programming service. Please include your code. We expect you to do some research yourself and show us what you have tried. We do not program for you. Take a look here on how to ask a question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Per @[Anand Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7188473/anand-pandey)'s comment, you definitely should post the code that you have tried.  That said, here are some things you could investigate to see if they would help your cause.

> [How do you customize/style codeigniter errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498091/how-do-you-customize-style-codeigniter-errors)
>
> [How to customize form validation errors in codeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271558/how-to-customize-form-validation-errors-in-codeigniter)
>
> [CodeIgniter highlight fields with errors on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157393/codeigniter-highlight-fields-with-errors-on-form-submission)

Also, on the off chance you are using Bootstrap with your application, here is another to look into.

> [How to use Bootrstrap error styling within CodeIgniter form
>   validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803176/how-to-use-bootrstrap-error-styling-within-codeigniter-form-validation)